# how to write formal proofs involving nxn matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i have problems like these:

Prove that if A is a nxn matrix, then tr(A-A^T)=0

Prove that if A and B are nxn matrices then tr(A+B) = tr(A) + tr(B).

I can clearly understand why these hold true and can plug in numbers endlessly but I have no idea how I am supposed to formally prove it.

I tried looking at other tip questions for proofs in general but they only say to read books etc., I want to know for this specific type of problem.

Comment: According to the definitions of basic matrix operations, what are the diagonal entries of $A^T$, $A-A^T$, $A+B$?

Comment: aij, 0, and aij+bij?

Comment: Now apply the definition of trace. That should get you to your results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to these proofs with a fixed, arbitrary $n$ is dealing with summation notation.  So, for example, let's do the easy one:

Let $A,B$ be $n \times n$ matrices with entries $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ respectively, where $i$ and $j$ go from $1$ to $n$.  By definitions, we may state that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \tr(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{kk}, \quad 
\tr(B) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{kk}
$$
Now, the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $(A + B)$ is $(a_{ij} + b_{ij})$.  It follows, then, that
$$
\tr(A + B) = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{kk} + b_{kk})
$$
Now, how do I know that this is equal to $\tr(A) + \tr(B)$?

A nice problem of this type that you may want to try is as follows: prove that $\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)$ for any $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and $n \times m$ matrix $B$.

Comment: because of some type of property of summation...

Comment: ...By which you mean commutativity/associativity.  Yes, that's right, and the key is that by writing things out in summation notation, I've made the relationship between them much more obvious.